# Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline and Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins Pipeline Job which has this code :

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

stage 'Build'
node('master'){
    svn 'http://mysvn/url'
    def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable
    def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()
    .
    .
}
```

The code is with unchecked 'sandbox' (as it presented on the picture).
[image]
and I get this error :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread
```

I am not familiar with the syntax for `Thread.currentThread()?.executable`
what does the '?' operator means.

I google it and found out about **jenkins job-dsl plugin** and didn't find anything about this operator.

I also tried the **Script Console Plugin** at : http://localhost:8080/script
and I fail for the same reason.

Does Pipeline Plugin support the Jenkins DSL-JOB ? should I import something in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-Access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job) is the related ticket and the answer from cloudbees.. Ping back from there:

```java
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it , and let you know :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's a groovy operator, '?' is to prevent NullpointerExceptions. It does the following only if the first is not null.

The Sandbox feature is to prevent certain calls so anybody can add scripts without admin approval, but very limited...

Answer (score 0):

```
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable
```

Firstly, the above sentence can be explained like this,

`Thread.currentThread()` will get the current running thread, in normal case, it will be a instance of Jenkins `Executor` class, there is a attribute inside this class,

```
    /**
 * {@link hudson.model.Queue.Executable} being executed right now, or null if the executor is idle.
 */
@GuardedBy("lock")
private Queue.Executable executable;
```

Jenkins `AbstractBuild` implement this interface, so it means you will actually get `AbstractBuild` instance back.

However, this sentence is not work for pipeline related jobs since pipe line project have different structure compared with old Jenkins jobs. It don't extend `AbstractBuild` class.

This is why your script is not working.

About your requirement, since there is no `AbstrctBuild` class, so a lot of methods are actually cannot be used, like the one you used.

No idea if there is a smart way to get the changset inside pipeline job, or maybe you need restructure your job to adapt pipeline plugin.

Br,

Tim

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Does the Jenkins job dsl can be used on the pipeline? It seems like Jenkins pipeline is dependent on this module , can I use this api?

Comment: what do you mean use the job dsl in pipeline? Any example?

Comment: ' steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName}")
        }'